# iOS Push Notifications always capitalized

Tags: ios, push-notification

Is there a way to modify the app name to not be all caps?

Push Notifications:

[image: Push Notifications]

Comment: There is no way to influence this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It will always be your bundle display name in all caps.